# Google Play requires that apps target API level 30 or higher on mac m1 chip

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I have an error on the mac m1 chip; on mac intel chip, I didn't have this error:

```
Google Play requires that apps target API level 30 or higher.
```

Build Gradle(app) is here:

```
buildscript {
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.michaelrocks.paranoid'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.hajitsu.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.2.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
//            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
//            multiDexEnabled true
//            useProguard true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
}
```

and build error is here too:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.3.0.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ed4d71ce9316dac5f2545f0cf5be7833/mediarouter-1.3.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6dcc77d5fc8906686084d94fe3f9b020/appcompat-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/29db00f06a8a06b588a6af7c7ef25e8e/jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3466c63a084b132c1d6b4236c1945221/jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a8da9dac75c25f0f6fa7955d4dc311fc/jetified-emoji2-1.0.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (30) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.media:media:1.4.1.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/96464e52982ac3d9f5d97a6e0237536c/media-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7c2322e9a5fc42a9be04af4d17b6f785/core-1.7.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/db23f8447110e0e53b77e072fd80edeb/jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
        Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
        AAR metadata file: /Users/hajitsu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e1e678c620701c025b8859fecad043fc/lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I try these steps but the error is not solved yet.

- uninstall android studio and install it again.
- remove SDK and download it again.
- remove Gradle and redownload it.
- upgrade the Gradle version.
- upgrade all libraries.
- change SDK version like 29 30 31 and etc

Comment: Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 31.

Comment: @Pawel: This does not appear to be related to `targetSdkVersion`. The errors cite `minCompileSdk`, which ties to the app's `compileSdkVersion`, not `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps.

1. Go to build.gradle (app-level)
2. Set your  **compileSdkVersion** to **33**.
3. Then set the **targetSdkVersion** to **31**.
4. Navigate to **Android Manifest.xml** then add this **android:exported="false"** or **android:exported="true"**. See [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported] for details.
5. Run **flutter build apk --release**